# OpenGL render to a OpenCV mat as texture and reuse it in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, opengl

I have a OpenCV mat that I want to render to with OpenGL. So I try to load the openCV mat as a texture via a code that I found online and render to that texture:

```
void BindCVMat2GLTexture(cv::Mat& image, GLuint& imageTexture)
{
    if (image.empty()) {
        std::cout << "image empty" << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);
        //glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_REPLACE);
        glGenTextures(1, &imageTexture);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, imageTexture);

        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

        // Set texture clamping method
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP);

        cv::cvtColor(image, image, CV_RGB2BGR);

        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,         // Type of texture
            0,                   // Pyramid level (for mip-mapping) - 0 is the top level
            GL_RGB,              // Internal colour format to convert to
            image.cols,          // Image width  i.e. 640 for Kinect in standard mode
            image.rows,          // Image height i.e. 480 for Kinect in standard mode
            0,                   // Border width in pixels (can either be 1 or 0)
            GL_RGB,              // Input image format (i.e. GL_RGB, GL_RGBA, GL_BGR etc.)
            GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,    // Image data type
            image.ptr());        // The actual image data itself
            //NULL);
    }
}
```

Then I create a FBO:

```
//init the texture
    GLuint imageTexture;
    BindCVMat2GLTexture(target, imageTexture);

    //init the frame buffer
    GLuint fbo = 0;
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &fbo);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);
    // Set "renderedTexture" as our colour attachement #0
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, imageTexture, 0);
```

Then I'm calling:

```
glViewport(0, 0, target.cols, target.rows);
MyDraw();
```

After this calls I use another function I found to copy the texture data back to an openCV mat:

```
cv::Mat GetOcvImgFromOglImg(GLuint ogl_texture_id)
{
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, ogl_texture_id);
    GLenum gl_texture_width, gl_texture_height;

    glGetTexLevelParameteriv(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_TEXTURE_WIDTH, (GLint*)&gl_texture_width);
    glGetTexLevelParameteriv(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_TEXTURE_HEIGHT, (GLint*)&gl_texture_height);

    unsigned char* gl_texture_bytes = (unsigned char*)malloc(sizeof(unsigned char)*gl_texture_width*gl_texture_height * 3);
    glGetTexImage(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0 /* mipmap level */, GL_BGR, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, gl_texture_bytes);

    return cv::Mat(gl_texture_height, gl_texture_width, CV_8UC3, gl_texture_bytes);
}
```

and call this by:

```
target = GetOcvImgFromOglImg(imageTexture);
```

Also I create triangle vertices and a vertex shader that simply leaves them untouched and a fragment shader that just puts out the color red. In theory I just want a red triangle drawn over this texture as a first step. However it is not working since I get no rendered image at all. I'm a very beginner with openGL and I can't find any solution by myself right now. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I solved my problem, which I should have posted more code to make an answer easier, by adding a VertexBufferObject which I totally ignored from the tutorial. Also and this is very important, I use SFML lib at the same time to display my frames. SFML also uses OpenGL internally. So I need to save and restore the OpenGL states which interfere with eachother.

I drop this link in case somebody has similar problems:
[using-opengl-together-with-the-graphics-module](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.4/window-opengl.php#using-opengl-together-with-the-graphics-module)

This added state save/restore before I use SFML together with the missing VAO code and a reset of OpenGL bindings after my Draw() method made it work. This might not be the most performant solution but for now it is a way to achieve what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

OpenCV store image as rows data tightly packed but might align them to certain byte boundaries may be 4 or 8 but we don't know that If you're lucky it will use 4-byte alignment which is default with OpenGL also.But it's best to manually set it with the pixel storage modes in order to be on the safe side:

`// use fast 4-byte alignment (default anyway) if possible
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, (image.step & 3) ? 1 : 4);`

`//set length of one complete row in data (doesn't need to equal image.cols)
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH, image.step/image.elemSize());`

Then you have to account for the fact that OpenCV stores images from top to bottom, while the GL uses bottom to top. To take care of this use following

`cv::flip(image, flipped, 0);
image = flipped;`

OpenCV stores color images in BGR format so uploading it as RGB would distort the colors. So use `GL_BGR` in `glTexImage2D`.

Comment: actually none of that solved my particular case, but I think it's because as you said 4-byte alignment is default anyway. Also no flipping was needed and as you can see in my code above I was using a openCV RGB2BGR conversion. So I could use your proposed method which does the same regarding the color format.